# VB.NET Count line number in textbox

Tags: vb.net

I use Fileystemwatcher to watch a certain folder on our network share and wan't to count the lines in a textbox.

I have 2 richtextboxes, the first one will display the line number and the second one displays the change/deleted/renamed file.

I am able to display the total of lines in a label, but also want to show the line numbers in a richtextbox, but the problem is that it adds the number to the current, it needs to add the number on a new line.

Hopefully the image will explain.

[image: example image]

```
Private Sub textFolderActiviteit_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles textFolderActiviteit.TextChanged
    textFolderActiviteit.SelectionStart = textFolderActiviteit.Text.Length
    textFolderActiviteit.SelectionLength = 0
    textFolderActiviteit.ScrollToCaret()
    textFolderActiviteit.Focus()
    Dim currentLineIndex As Integer = textFolderActiviteit.GetLineFromCharIndex(textFolderActiviteit.SelectionStart)
    Me.Label2.Text = String.Format("{0}", currentLineIndex + 1)
    Me.textLineCount.Text = String.Format("{0}", currentLineIndex + 1 & vbCrLf)
End Sub

Private Sub textLineCount_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles textLineCount.TextChanged
    textLineCount.SelectionStart = textLineCount.Text.Length
    textLineCount.SelectionLength = 0
    textLineCount.ScrollToCaret()
    textLineCount.Focus()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but couldn't you just put the VbCrlf before the line number?

```
Me.textLineCount.Text = String.Format("{0}", vbCrLf & (currentLineIndex + 1).ToString())
```

Comment: Does not work, it still counts up instead of adding 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: So you don't want 1,2,3,4... you want 1,2,4,8,16?  Or what?

Comment: yes i wan't a follow up, but look at the image is just counts instead of putting the new line number on a new line.

Comment: Wouldn't the new line number go in order?  Line 1, Line 2, Line 3.  Not Line 1, Line 2, Line 4, Line 8.